# WCF service and force time out after certain interval

Tags: c#, wcf, cookies, session-timeout

in asp.net after authentication if we stay idle for more than 20 minute then session goes time out or expire. so i like to know is there anything similar exist in wcf that when any client will consume my service and when they are stay idle after authenticated more than 20 minute then session should expire and as a result client need to provide credential again.

just for security reason how could i design our wcf service that when client will call my service and successfully authenticated but after authentication they do not interact with service for more than 20 minute then when client back and interact then he/she will get message like "your session expire....login again"

guide me to develop this kind of wcf service. thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [WCF Session Timeout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/968939/wcf-session-timeout)

Comment: so i just like to know should i work with session inactivityTimeout or ReceiveTimeout /SendTimeout to reach my goal?